# Присоединительные члены предложения в вопросе

Tags: пунктуация, присоединительный

> Вас ждать(,) и если ждать, то во сколько?

1. В данном случае нужна ли запятая (насколько я помню, если в предложении обе части являются по своему характеру вопросительными, запятая перед соединительным союзом не ставится)?
2. Является ли союз "и" в данном случае присоединительным? Влияет ли это на постановку запятой?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Вас ждать, и **если ждать, то во сколько**?*

Здесь нет присоединительных отношений, но есть **соединительные** отношения.

**Сложная** конструкция:  **три** предикативные основы, союз ***И*** связывает простое предложение и СПП.

Запятая ставится в общем порядке, без учета **вопросительной** интонации.

Общая вопросительная интонация возможна в ***ССП***, где союз И связывает **два простых предложения**.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы верно заметили, что союз *и* имеет присоединительное значение. Поэтому запятую ставим:

*Вас ждать, и если ждать, то во сколько?*